# Index of number(s) in list in JAVA

Tags: java, arrays, list, arraylist, indexing

I need to have a program that asks the user for a number, and reports that number's index in the list. If the number is not found, the program should not print anything.

**Example:**

```
Sample Output:
1
2
3
3
4
Search for? 3
3 is at index 2
3 is at index 3
```

This is what I have written but the put is looping multiple times. Can you suggest fixing it?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class IndexOf {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        while (true) {
            int input = Integer.valueOf(scanner.nextLine());
            if (input == -1) {
                break;
            }

            list.add(input);
        }

        System.out.println("Search for? ");
        int src = scanner.nextInt();
        int ind = 0;

        for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++){
            int num = list.get(i);
            if(src == num){
                ind = list.indexOf(src);
            }
            System.out.println(src + " is at index " + ind);
        }

    }
}
```

EDIT

> Input: 1 2 3 3 4 -1
>
> Search for? 3 Output: 3 is at index 0 3 is at index 0 3 is at index 2 3 is at index 2 3 is at index 2 ///So it must be only one sentence for each index. Even if I put after "for" loop, it only output the first if index.

Comment: Shouldn't `System.out.println(src + " is at index " + ind);` only happen *if* (hint hint) you find the number? That is only *if* `src == num`? (hint hint)

Comment: You also really don't need to declare an extra `int ind = 0;` variable for the index in the loop. You are using a simple for loop that already uses a counter variable that represents the current index you are checking `int i =0`.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca you are right, it must happen. But I want to output all indexes which exist in the list (let's say in the list there are 2 same numbers).

Comment: Reading your code superficially it seems to make sense. Can you provide an input where the output will be wrong and explain what should have happened instead?

Comment: @AminMousavi yes, and you should print it only when you find it, not at every iteration. That's what I mean.

Comment: @LajosArpad sure.

Input:
1
2
3
3
4
-1
Search for? 
3



Output:
3 is at index 0
3 is at index 0 
3 is at index 2 
3 is at index 2 
3 is at index 2

///So it must be only one sentence for each index. Even if I put after "for" loop, it only output the first if index.

Comment: `System.out.println` is after your `if`, causing false positives for all elements of your collection. You need to move it inside the `if`.

Comment: @LajosArpad also `ind = list.indexOf(src);` besides being wrong (because `indexOf` will always return the index of the first instance) you don't need this. Just print `i`.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca it has worked. I did changed it, appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see a single problem in your code, that is, you print everything, not only the matches. To solve that you need to put your `System.out.println` into the `if`, like this:

```
        for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++){
            int num = list.get(i);
            if(src == num){
                ind = i;
                System.out.println(src + " is at index " + ind);
            }
        }
```

Let me know if anything else was wrong.

Comment: It is correct but it is looping the index sentence. It is making the program not work properly. Do you suggest anything for it?

Comment: @AminMousavi I see you have answered my question in the comment section of your question. I will look into it and return to this comment.

Comment: @AminMousavi Can you provide an input and an output for the code changed based on the suggestion in this answer and explain how is it wrong? Here, for your input I would expect index 2 and 3 to be shown as matches. Can you test this?

Comment: @AminMousavi edited my answer since then, fixing a problem that messed up the indexes, which I was taking from your original question and forgot to fix it.

Comment: thank you. Now, it is working without any issues.

Comment: @AminMousavi happy to help. If my answer helped you solve your problem, then you might consider accepting it as the correct answer.

Comment: is done already.